# Using IdentityDbContext in a Web API returns: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-identity-3

I get this error when calling from Angular client:

Failed to load http://localhost:57873/users: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

If not using a context derived from IdentityDbContext, I am able to connect to the server just fine.

I assume the following code may be relevant.

**startup.cs**

```
namespace WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();

            // ****** the following line does not give the CORS error *****    
            //services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"));


            // ****** CORS error occurs when the following statment is used *****
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAutoMapper();

            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            // configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            // configure DI for application services
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            // global cors policy
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

Why am I getting that CORS error?

Comment: Sometimes Google Chrome and other browsers hide the actual error. You are getting CORS, but It's an Internal Server Error, something is not right with your application.

Comment: @Fals, I have a break on the first line of code in the Web API method and it is never hit when that . But, yes, something is not right. Or Visual Studio is messing something up.

Comment: is your code. Probably the connection string is pointing to an inexistent SQL server or the database must be migrated or created via update database command.

Comment: @Fals, I believe you are right, as it is consistent with a new example I have been playing with. Thank you for your response!